# How to more easily make coverpoints for each bit in a bus?

Tags: system-verilog

In a design there is a bus with 4 bits, thus `alfa[3:0]`, and I want to make a covergroup that shows if all bit have been both 0 and 1.

One way to do this coule be to write it out like:

```
covergroup alfa_cv @(posedge clk);
  coverpoint alfa[0];
  coverpoint alfa[1];
  coverpoint alfa[2];
  coverpoint alfa[3];
endgroup

alfa_cv alfa_covergroup = new;
```

But is there an easier way to make coverpoints to cover each of the bits in a bus?

Comment: You could just do the following inside covergroup: `coverpoint alfa;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually code coverage includes toggle coverage. You shouldn't have to create a covergroup for this. But you can create an array of covergroups

```
covergroup cg(input int index, ref bit [31:0] bus) @(posedge clk);
  each_bit: coverpoint bus[index];
  option.per_instance = 1;
endgroup

cg cgbits[32];

for (int index=0; index<$size(alfa);index++)  
   cgbits[index] = new(index,alfa);
```

Comment: Thanks, useful inspiration, but had to do some modifications due to reported errors, e.g. had to declare `index` as `genvar index;`.

Comment: That depends on the context of where the `for` loop is.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone mentioned over here, you don't need to write a covergroup for this purpose, as the toggle coverage will take care of it.

However, if you want to write a covergroup then you can directly use `alfa` as coverpoint, as follow.

```
covergroup alfa_cv @(posedge clk);
  coverpoint alfa;
endgroup
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion, but that gives a cover group for all the combinations of values in 4 bits, thus 2 ** 4 = 16 combinations, and not only 0 and 1 for each of the bits, thus 4 * 2 = 8 combinations.